# I want show the div when mouse hover on it in time out and hide it on mouse out

Tags: jquery

I want show the div when mouse hover on it in time out and hide it on mouse out

i've like this but its not working properly

```
$(".ad-item").hover(

    function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var timer =
            setTimeout(function () {
                $this.children('.content').show();
            }, 500);
    },
    function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $(this).children('.content').hide();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this. Check the working code here. 
http://jsfiddle.net/linkmanishgupta/cKRDH/

Here is the script:-

```
 var timer;
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("div").hover(
     function () {
         timer = setTimeout(function () {
             $("div").children().hide();
         }, 500);
     }, function () {
         clearTimeout(timer);
         $("div").children().show();
     });
 });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can someone please format the above code of mine. I am facing problem posting codes in stackoverflow. :(

Answer (score 0):

You're mouseout fn wont work because it doesn't have access to `timer`, because that var is initialized inside the other function. Try this:

```
var timer;    

$(".ad-item").hover(

    function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        timer =
            setTimeout(function () {
                $this.children('.content').show();
            }, 500);
    },
    function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $(this).children('.content').hide();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ad-item").mouseover(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
         $this.children('.content').show();
    });
    $(".ad-item").mouseout(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
         $(this).children('.content').hide();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use timeout then timer variable has to be global:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var timer
    $(".aditem").hover(
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            timer =
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $this.children('.content').fadeIn();
                }, 500);
        },
        function () {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            $(this).children('.content').hide();
        }
    );
});
```

But in your case you also can avoid using timer if you use some Jquery effects such as fadeIn with slow animation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".aditem").hover(
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.children('.content').fadeIn(1500);

        },
        function () {
            $(this).children('.content').hide();
        }
    );
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gZ7ah/1/)